# Excel power query, error handling for fallback connection/OleDb data source

Tags: error-handling, db2, powerquery, oledbconnection, m

I have a PowerQuery connected to DB2 Data Source, but because of some kind of load balancing the DB Server changes periodically (ip also changes), There is no way for me to know beforehand which data source (IP), I should use until I try it and see that it errors out, then I have to use the other one, I googled for error handling in PowerQuery and found some examples of error handling but this examples did not apply to my case, most of them handled errors AFTER the connection was made or were preventing errors on missing columns or files not found, I tried to adjust the examples to my case but was not able to.

What I want is just try one IP and if it fails then use the other one.

```
let

//fParametros("ParamQuery",1) is the "standard" Server/Ip address (provider=IBMDADB2.IBMDBCL1;data source=CP3;location=pn8us7ldbcp3.us.mycompany.com:5912)

dbSource = fParametros("ParamQuery",1),

//fParametros("ParamQuery",5) is the "Alternate" Server/Ip address (provider=IBMDADB2.IBMDBCL1;data source=CP3;location=pn8us7ldbcp3h.us.mycompany.com:5912)

AltdbSource = fParametros("ParamQuery",5),
pOrden = Text.From(fParametros("ParamQuery",2)),

//Create the query
dbQuery = "SELECT SAPCP3.vbak.VBELN SO , SAPCP3.vbap.posnr PoLine , SAPCP3.vbep.ETENR Sch_Line , SAPCP3.vbap.matnr Part_Number,SAPCP3.makt.maktx Description,SAPCP3.vbap.kwmeng Qty ,SAPCP3.vbep.BMENG Conf_qty ,SAPCP3.vbap.vrkme UOM ,SAPCP3.vbap.netpr SalesPrice ,SAPCP3.vbap.kpein LotSize FROM SAPCP3.vbak JOIN SAPCP3.vbap ON SAPCP3.VBAp.VBELN = SAPCP3.VBAK.VBELN JOIN SAPCP3.vbep ON SAPCP3.vbep.vbeln = SAPCP3.vbak.vbeln AND SAPCP3.vbap.posnr  = SAPCP3.vbep.posnr JOIN sapcp3.makt ON sapcp3.vbap.matnr=sapcp3.makt.matnr WHERE SAPCP3.VBAK.VKORG = '4000' AND (SAPCP3.vbep.edatu >= '20190701') AND SAPCP3.vbak.VBELN ="& pOrden & " ORDER BY SAPCP3.vbak.VBELN",

//Get the data
Source = OleDb.DataSource(dbSource, [Query=dbQuery]),

//Failed Attempt to handle the error:    

TestForError= try Source,

//next line does not work, I get error saying Source is already defined/declared
Source = if TestForError[HasError] then OleDb.DataSource(AltdbSource, [Query=dbQuery]) else OleDb.DataSource(dbSource, [Query=dbQuery])

in

Source
```

I also Tried the following:

```
.
.
.

//Get the data
Source = OleDb.DataSource(dbSource, [Query=dbQuery]),

//Failed Attempt to handle the error:
TestForError= try Source,

Output = if TestForError[HasError] then OleDb.DataSource(AltdbSource, [Query=dbQuery]) else OleDb.DataSource(dbSource, [Query=dbQuery])

in

Output


//This last part works if the dbSource is correct, but if it is not it doesnt catch the error and gives me the Connection error shown below:
```

> DataSource.Error: OLE DB:  SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "172.16.0.1".  Communication function detecting the error: "connect".  Protocol specific error code(s): "10061", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001
>   Details:
>       DataSourceKind=OleDb
>       DataSourcePath=data source=CP3;location=pn8us7ldbcp3.us.mycompany.com:5912;provider=IBMDADB2.IBMDBCL1
>       Message= SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "172.16.0.1".  Communication function detecting the error: "connect".  Protocol specific error code(s): "10061", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001
>       ErrorCode=-2147467259

**I want to connect to dbSource (172.16.0.1) and if it is not possible then connect to AltdbSource (172.16.0.2)**

Currently I have 2 identical excel sheeets and user needs to open one or the other if he gets the connection error, I want it to change automatically.

Comment: If you have a clustered Db2, then your apps should be connecting to a service-address, instead of to the individual Db2-servers that clustered. Talk to your DBA to get the correct floating IP-address or service-DNS-name for your cluster. The idea is that the database changes between hostnames that the apps just reconnect to the *same* ip-address/service-name. That's the easiest way to handle such things.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I already tried this but it is a really cumbersome process to get anything from them, they barely accepted to give us access rights, they prefer to handle all request by themselves (charge us also of course), they are not very happy that we have read access, and would like us to do everything via SAP GUI ("They" are our service providers, a subdivision of our own company), so I would still like to know if there is another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `TestForError = try OleDb.DataSource(BadSource)` isn't working because `OleDb.DataSource(...)` returns a table value than only produces an error when trying to enumerate rows.

What if you change `TestForError` to drill into the first row if it exists:

```
TestForError= try Source{0}?,
```

---

If that still doesn't work, next try indexing into a table cell in the first row.

Comment: Not sure I understood you, dbQuery is selecting a few records already, if the source is not ok I cannot even connect to it, so it SHOULD raise an error.

Comment: Table values can be lazy, i.e. they don't actually run the SQL query until some code checks the columns or starts enumerating rows. I don't remember the implementation, but OleDb might even open a connection first then run the SQL later. 

As a really simple example of laziness, imagine you make Concat by concatenating a simple list { 1 } with a List.Generate() that errors when enumerating the first value. Concat is a valid list value, but the values inside haven't been evaluated yet. You should be able to run Concat{0} to get 1, but then enumerating the second value Concat{1} will error.

Comment: I understand what you mean about laziness, but in this case the connection cannot be done to the wrong dbsource, so no query to be run there is not even an open connection made. (first row will NEVER exist since i cannot connect to the DB)